# Linq to SQL, contains in where clause repeated values

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a simple table of items, called "ITEMS":

```
id  description
--  -----------
 1  Something
 2  Another thing
 3  Best thing
```

I have a list of Int32 which are item IDs I'd like to show:

```
List<Int32> currentItemsCodes = new List<int>();
```

For this example currentItemsCodes contains 1,2,2,3

Currently I have this Linq-to-SQL:

```
var itemDescriptions = (from a in db.ITEMS
where currentItemsCodes.Contains(a.id)
select new {a.id, a.description});
```

What this returns is:

```
1,Something
2,Another thing
3,Best thing
```

I need to return two "Another things":

```
1,Something
2,Another thing
2,Another thing
3,Best thing
```

Or if currentItemsCodes was 3,3,3,3 I would need 4 x "Best thing" returned

Answer (score 3):

You should do a inner join in linq to get what you are looking for. Use the below linq query to do that.

```
   var itemDescriptions = (from a in db.ITEMS
            join c in currentItemsCodes
                on a.id equals c
            select new {a.id, a.description});
```

Comment: This compiles and runs, but I am then trying to do a foreach on the returned items and it falls over:

System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233067
  Message=Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

Comment: can you share the code... it works for me. see the code below for sample.

 foreach (var itemDescription in itemDescriptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(itemDescription.id.ToString()+"---"+itemDescription.description);
            }

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `join` clause for that:

```
var itemDescriptions = (from item in db.ITEMS
                       join i in currentItemsCodes on item.id equals i
                       select new
                       {
                           id = item.id,
                           description = item.description
                       }).ToList();
```

Comment: This behaves the same as Prashant's answer above.
This compiles and runs, but I am then trying to do a foreach on the returned items and it falls over:

System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233067
  Message=Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

Comment: You might try adding `ToList()` to the end of your query. Put parentheses around the above query and append `.ToList()` - see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var x = db.items;
var itemDescriptions = (from a in currentItemsCodes
select new {a, x[a].description});
```

As in Kris's comments substitute for [a] a method to access the items by id

Comment: db.Items is not a dictionary, it doesn't have an indexer defined. This doesn't even compile.

Comment: Surely there must be some method by which table items can be accessed by id?

Comment: Of course, but your answer does not use it. Furthermore, your approach will generate two roudtrips to the database for every index in currentItemsCodes.

Comment: @Kris Fair comment. Made adjustments.

Comment: I can't get this to compile, get this error on both x[a]
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.Linq.Table<ITEMS>'

Comment: As in comments above, you need to provide a method by which you can access `description` by `id`. This depends on details of your implementation which I don't know. Or convert table, x, to a dictionary or list or array on the first line. eg `db.items.ToDictionary().